# Running files in the current window with batch

Tags: batch-file, window

This is pretty hard to explain so I'll do my best.

When I use the `start` command in Batch, It'll create a new window etc.

I'm trying to make my own console batch script that isn't as annoying as cmd.exe.

Problem is running commands like `help`, `echo` and so on in the current window.

My current code is

```
:console
set COMMAND=n
set /p COMMAND=%~dp0console.exe^> %=%
if %COMMAND%==exit exit
start %COMMAND%
rem Wait 1000
goto console
```

I'm using it with Batch to EXE Converter so `rem Wait 1000` is valid.

The big problem with the script is that if a user types `help` or `echo` and any other commands you can run normally in cmd.exe, it'll open a new cmd.exe window and run the script. I do not want this to happen, is there a way to solve the problem?

Things I've tried:

- Instead of using `start %COMMAND%` I just used `%COMMAND%`. This
  resulted in an error.

(Will add on this list when things that don't work are suggested)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

```
call %command%
```

Which will wait until the command is over

```
start /b %command%
```

Which will start the command in the current window

Comment: note to the OP, if you run `call` it can change variables in the original context, whereas `start /b` cant because start actually opens a new process. whereas if you want to collect the exit value (errorlevel) than you should use start.